# Tag rename request: emberdata to ember-data

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-synonyms

As of today, there are a few tags around EmberJS topic:

- [emberjs](/questions/tagged/emberjs)
- [emberdata](/questions/tagged/emberdata)
- [ember-router](/questions/tagged/ember-router)

We are missing coherence between them.

`emberjs` is already aliased as `ember`, which is a good thing, going to the right direction, I think *(By the way, it should definitely be renamed)*.

`ember-router` was created later, and is coherent as it is opened to modularity: future tags may be created as `ember-xxx`.

`emberdata` is a problematic case: I have enough privileges to alias it (`ember-data`), but the system does not make difference between `emberdata` and `ember-data`, so it refuses me to create the alias...

What we should have at the end is, IMHO:

- `ember` *(currently emberjs but renaming pending...)*
- `ember-data` *(currently emberdata, but **problematic renaming!**)*
- `ember-router` *(already here)*

Thanks for moderator's attention. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done the following:

- Merged [emberjs](/questions/tagged/emberjs) with [ember.js](/questions/tagged/ember.js) to follow current tagging conventions.
- Merged [emberdata](/questions/tagged/emberdata) with [ember-data](/questions/tagged/ember-data)